# Where to place if statement for login redirect in magento?

Tags: php, magento, web

Hi so basically I need my page to redirect to login/register.html I'm currently planning on using:

```
if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect(Mage::getUrl("customer/account/login")); 
}
```

problem is I'm don't know where to place the syntax I tried placing it in the pre dispatch function in the index controller of my module  but it didn't work
I was wondering where do I place this? do I use an event? is there a better way to implement it? I'm using magento btw

the flow is Navigation is clicked-> check if user is logged in -> if not redirect to login/register page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Check available actions
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
 */
public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();

    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your solution.